# Microarray data: multiple t-tests

Tags: r

The Problem:

Microarrays enable the biologist to measure the expression level of genes, in humans or other species.  In some studies, the gene expression level is measured in a number of individuals, some with a disease and some without (control group), to identify what genes are dierentially expressed.  The goal is to understand the role of genes in the development of the considered disease.  Read as much of the following paper as you feel inspired to, and enough to understand the basics: http://www.pnas.org/content/96/12/6745.full The corresponding dataset (after some processing) is available here: https://github.com/ramhiser/datamicroarray/blob/master/data/alon.RData A simple (and somewhat outdated) method for identifying dierentially expressed genes is to per-form a (two-sided) Student t-test for each gene comparing the two groups.  Write code that carries this out.  The result should be a p-value for each gene.  Then apply all the methods seen in lecture for controlling the FWER or the FDR.

My attempt:

```
m=62
dat = alon
summary(dat)
y = as.factor(alon$y)
y
nrow(alon$x)
pval = numeric(m)
for (i in 1:m) {
  pval[i] = t.test(alon[i,1:5], alon[i,-(1:5)])$p.value
}
```

but my code is giving me errors with the dimensions of alon[i, 1:5]

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (you need to use alon$x to point to the matrix of data you have in the list alon):

```
m=62
dat = alon
summary(dat)
y = as.factor(alon$y)
y
nrow(alon$x)
pval = numeric(m)
for (i in 1:m) {
   pval[i] = t.test(alon$x[i,1:5], alon$x[i,-(1:5)])$p.value
}
```

Comment: Figured that out right after I posted! Thanks. 

Do you know how I would adjust this code to perform a permutation t-test for each gene? It now asks to calibrate the t-ratio statistic by permutation by permuting the subjects and recomputing all the t-ratios for all the genes

Comment: If you can form your permutation  question precisely, then you might have some success posting it on stats.stackexchange.com. Just remember you should make an effort to show what you have done to solve the question. Not too many will study the paper you gave above. Good luck